# Exporting SharePoint Lists As Templates With Lookup Fields

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a requirement to create list templates from preexisting lists in SharePoint (Wss3/MOSS2007), with content included.  The problem is that these lists contain Lookup fields, and after you deploy a new list from the template they become detatched from their parent list, and you also cannot modify these fields to update where they take their information from.

Whats the best way to handle this?  Its primarily for setting up development versions of already existing lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't exactly simple, but [here](http://mindsharpblogs.com/todd/archive/2005/11/11/853.aspx) is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use Content Migration Wizard from Codeplex (http://www.codeplex.com/SPDeploymentWizard) to copy both the lookup and the referencing list to your dev server.